# Storing JTextArea content into an array and using it again later

Tags: java

I'm trying to take text (transactions) from a JTextArea and save it to an ArrayList and then clicking a button to make it come back later.

I made the ArrayList in the class Transaction.java:

```
ArrayList<String> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
```

When clicking the create button (In a different class that extends JFrame called TransApp.java), this is done at the end of the code:

```
t.transactions.add(TextArea.getText());
```

And finally, when using a button and a JSpinner, this code is used (Also in TransApp.java):

```
    Transaction t = new Transaction((int) TransNumSpin.getValue(), null, null, null, 0, 0);
    int i = (int) TransNumSpin.getValue();
    TextArea.setText(t.gotoTrans(i));
```

So, my question is, why is this not working properly? I do not have much experience with Java and what experience I do have, I do not have with storing anything. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Without seeing more of the code no-one will be able to help you accurately. Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Follow the advise above. However it seems you need maybe a for loop to get the values, and call the arraylist to add elements thru a method instead.